# Why does Application event log get cleared when I remove this custom even log

Tags: powershell, windows-event-log

I am using powershell cmdlets to create a new event-log, register a source and log events.
I experience some unexpected behavior. I created a new log with an arbitrary name by issuing the command:

```
New-EventLog -LogName SchedulerWakeUpTask -Source devops
```

I have verified in Event Viewer that it has appeared in "Applications and services logs" directory. I then created an event with

```
Write-EventLog -LogName SchedulerWakeUpTask -Source devops -EventId 1000 -Message "All good."
```

but the event didn't get logged in the correct log, but in the Application log instead. It resembles the behavior described in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/265430/how-do-i-fix-a-custom-event-viewer-log-that-merges-automatically-with-the-applic).
In log properties I have verified that my custom log has been assigned a specific separate log file with path `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\SchedulerWakeUpTask.evtx`. Having checked that, I then removed the log by issuing command

```
Remove-EventLog -LogName SchedulerWakeUpTask
```

After that, the empty log has disappeared from the event viewer, but also the whole Application log has been wiped out clean. Why?

Seeing the havoc already present I decided to test this a little more. The test concludes that:

- source name doesn't matter
- application event log consistently gets cleared every time I create and remove custom log with this particular name again
- application event log does not get cleared when I attempt to remove this custom log if it doesn't exist
- application event log does not get cleared when I create another custom event log with an arbitrary name of SchedulerWakeUpTask2, or SchedulerWakeUpTas, or SchedulerWakes, or kapusta, or whatever;
- application event log does not get cleared when I remove only the source associated with the custom log
- when custom log is created again and an event is emitted with `Write-EventLog` it's again only visible in `Application` event log
- it's not a visual glitch with Event Viewer, `Get-EventLog -LogName Application` says `No match` and the assigned event file has been truncated (used to be over 100MB IIRC, but it's size is a negligent 70kB now)

Comment: Try to restart Windows Event Log Service after creating a custom log.

Comment: @Vadim thanks for the suggestion. I believe it may resolve this instance of the problem, but surely it will not fix the root cause.